# alert the innerHTML of <a> tags

Tags: javascript, html

I have a java script code as below, it is supposed to change the color of the "a" tags and

alert their inner HTML:

```
function change(n){
    for(i=1;i<=6;i++){
        document.getElementById('nav_'+i).style.color='#666666';}
        document.getElementById('nav_'+n).style.color='#FEA563';
        var p=document.getElementById('nave_'+n).innerHTML;
        alert(p);
    }
}
```

The HTML goes as follows. But the alert does not work.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="top_nav">
    <a id="nav_1" onclick="change(1);" href="#">aaaa</a> |
    <a id="nav_2" onclick="change(2);"href="#">bbbb</a> |
    <a id="nav_3" onclick="change(3);"href="#">ccccc</a> |
    <a id="nav_4" onclick="change(4);"href="#">ddddd</a> |
    <a id="nav_5" onclick="change(5);"href="#">eeeee</a> |
    <a id="nav_6" onclick="change(6);"href="#">fffff</a>
    </div>
```

How can I have access to the innerHTML of the "a" tag that I click on it?

Comment: you have `getElementById('nave_'+n)` should be `getElementById('nav_'+n)`

Comment: `nave` is not equal to `nav`.

Comment: change `nave` to `nav`

Comment: Not related to your basic problem, but you are resetting the color and content of `nav_N` each time through the loop. Move those lines outside the loop. For readability, I would put a space before the `href` attributes on the `a` tags.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution would be to do the following:

```js
function change(elem) {
    var a = document.getElementById('top_nav').children
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i].style.color = '#666666';
    }
    elem.style.color = '#FEA563';
    alert(elem.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="top_nav">
        <a id="nav_1" onclick="change(this)" href="#">aaaa</a> |
        <a id="nav_2" onclick="change(this)" href="#">bbbb</a> |
        <a id="nav_3" onclick="change(this)" href="#">ccccc</a> |
        <a id="nav_4" onclick="change(this)" href="#">ddddd</a> |
        <a id="nav_5" onclick="change(this)" href="#">eeeee</a> |
        <a id="nav_6" onclick="change(this)" href="#">fffff</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Passing `this` to the `onclick` event handler makes it aware of the element that was clicked. And, since all your `a` elements are grouped inside the `top_nav` `div`, you can simple cycle through all of it's children to change their color.

Here's a working Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyEstilles/m1960yyL/.